# Stream an arraylist into a fixed two dimensional array and print?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, apache-poi, java-stream

I've been successful at reading an XLS worksheet to an `ArrayList`. Now the tricky part is that I'm trying to map this to a fixed two dimensional array. `ArrayList(i) --> Array(x)(y)` Where `i = 1705` and `x = 155` and `y = 11` respectively.

Edit: Maybe I wasn't clear on the questions part as stated. 
I'm trying to copy the elements of the below mentioned Excel (Book1.xls) to a two dimensional array. So far I've been succesful into copying ti into an arraylist: "singleRows". But I'm having trouble moving them to the two dimensional array: "myReplicate".

I want to use the elements of this array to create SQL insert statements.
Hope I haven't missed anything in specifying the requirement.

```
package excelread3;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;

public class ExcelRead3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
         FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\CReaper\\Documents\\docs\\Opice\\Book1.xls"));
         HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
         HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
         HSSFRow firstRow = sheet.getRow(0);
         int rowcount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
         int colcount = firstRow.getLastCellNum();
         Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
         ArrayList<Object> singleRows = new ArrayList<Object>();
         ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
         while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
         {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            for( int i =1 ; i < colcount ; i++ )
            {
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    singleRows.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                }
            }
            list.add(singleRows);
        }
        // System.out.println(rowcount + "\n");
        // System.out.println(colcount + "\n");
        Stream<Object> stringStream;
        stringStream = singleRows.stream();
        String[][] myReplicate = new String[rowcount][colcount];
        myReplicate = stringStream.toArray(new String[stringStream.size()]);
        for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < colcount; j++)
            {
                System.out.printf("%5d ", myReplicate[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        file.close();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to convert the ArrayList to a Stream before filling the array elements.

Comment: Why is every line in your code a comment?  Also, back away from the mechanics and explain what you're trying to _accomplish_.  This question is unclear and likely to get downvoted and put on hold.

Comment: Hi there, this was the first time I was trying to insert code into stackoverflow and it kept stating that the code wasn't formatted correctly till I commented each line (Ctrl + K).. What I'm trying to do here is map the excel to a two dimensional array and later create cases for sql insert statements..

Answer (score 0):

Just checked across for mapping an excel to a two dimensional array.
And found this:

```
        String[][] excelData = new String[numRows][numCols];
        for (int i=0; i<numRows; i++) 
                {
                HSSFRow row = mySheet.getRow(i);
                for (int j=0; j<numCols; j++) 
                    {
                    HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                    String value = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    excelData[i][j] = value;
                    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(excelData));     
                    }   
                System.out.println();
                }       
                    }   
                System.out.println();
                }
```

This helped me further my requirement.
Thanks for the attention spared for this.